# Playwright nested projects

Tags: playwright

I have a need to build the following nested projects using Playwright

```
  projects: [ // this would be the root for all projects
    {
      name: 'Global Setup',
      testDir: 'global-setup',
      teardown: 'Global Teardown'
    },
    projects: [ // project A
      {
        name: 'Setup Project A',
        testDir: 'setup-proj-a',
        dependencies: ['Global Setup'],
        teardown: 'teardown-proj-a'
      },
      {
        name: 'Feature 1',
        testDir: 'proj-a/feature-1',
        dependencies: ['Setup Project A'],
        use: {
          ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
          storageState: STORAGE_STATE
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Feature 2',
        testDir: 'proj-a/feature-2',
        dependencies: ['Setup Project A'],
        use: {
          ...devices['Desktop Chrome']
        },
        fullyParallel: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Teardown Project A',
        testDir: 'teardown-proj-a'
      }

    projects: [ // project B
      {
        name: 'Setup Project B',
        testDir: 'setup-proj-b',
        dependencies: ['Global Setup'],
        teardown: 'teardown-proj-b'
      },
      {
        name: 'Feature 2',
        testDir: 'proj-b/feature-2',
        dependencies: ['Setup Project B'],
        use: {
          ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
          storageState: STORAGE_STATE
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Teardown Project B',
        testDir: 'teardown-proj-b'
      }
    {
      name: 'Global Teardown',
      testDir: 'global-teardown'
    }
```

Does Playwright support such an approach? Or is there a way to achieve this structure with Playwright?

And on the same topic, is it possible to have a generic `playwright.config.ts` file at root level, that can be extended by `playwright.config.ts` files in each project folder?

Currently I have one full `playwright.config.ts` file in each folder, with 70% of the options being identical for all projects

Comment: What is the reason for needing nested projects here? Couldnt you achieve the same with regular projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either method will work. Here's the process...

## Single config file (recommended)

You should be able to use a single `playwright.config.ts` for all of your projects. Remember that within a [project config](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject), you have access to the following properties:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  projects: [{
    // for selecting test files
    testDir, testMatch, testIgnore, 
    // for configuring project-specific settings:
    use,
  }],
});
```

In one shared file, it's easy to share config:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  projects: [{
    ...defaultConfig,
    name: 'Project A',
  }, {
    ...defaultConfig,
    name: 'Project B',
  }],
});
```

Perhaps the only gotcha is that you may want to match sure each project had a dedicated browser state (e.g. login, cookies, etc) for use across each of that project's features.

Playwright has a good article about [sharing state](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#option-1-project-dependencies). The only caveat is that you will want to match sure each project stores it's state in a different location from the other.

## Multiple config files (for monorepo)

Of course, you can use multiple `playwright.config.ts` files, but I would only recommend it if you're in a monorepo, where the projects are legitimately separate.

If you wanted to go this route, you can import the values from your base config file and extend them.

```js
// ./playwright.config.ts
export default defineConfig({});

// ./packages/project-a/playwright.config.ts
import baseConfig from '../../playwright.config.ts';

export default defineConfig({
  ...baseConfig,
  // etc
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try with the Multiple config files (for monorepo). Short info about the need:

I want to have dedicated test projects for each smaller features of the app.
Instead of having a big test project, with a lot of dependencies between tests and test data, I rather prefer to have smaller contexts - where each small project will create its own test env, run the tests, teardown and clean.

We also want to avoid having many repos to maintain. And then in a monorepo, I need certain amount of base config in root and then sub-project dependencies (setup -> run stuff-> clean